# how to map a Rails app to a certain URL path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

Hey, Guys
I'm now learning starting up the Rails on my VPS server, Now I can visit my app rails my `thin server` by a 3000 port number, something like this `http://mydomain:3000`,

But I want to map this app to the url like `http://mydomain/railsapp1`, so when I add a railsapp2 for testing purpose, it won't mess up my railsapp1.

Should I add something in the `thin` configuration file? or I should use `nginx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just start railsapp2 on port 3001 if you want to have both running at the same time

Rails 2

```
script/server -p 3001
```

Rails 3

```
rails server -p 3001
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you open to using Passenger (ModRails)?  You could then use Nginx and setup your Rails apps under different subdirectories.

General information for installing Passenger in Nginx can be found here: http://www.modrails.com/install.html

You can see more information here on setting up Rails in subdirectories: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this cool stuff, But right now the track of my site is not high, so I'm still stick to the thin server, and switch to the passenger when I need.